# What is path for hive beeline command history file?

Tags: hive, path, command, history, beeline

Using beeline to connect hive and running multiple commands.I am not able to find the path where I can view the history of all executed hive commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view all executed beeline commands details from following path:

```
/$HOME/.beeline/
```

For example if you are starting beeline as root user then file path will be:

```
/root/.beeline/history
```

Environment details:

```
Os:RHEL6 and RHEL7
Apache Hive (version 1.1.0-cdh5.12.2)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.1.0-cdh5.12.2)
Beeline version 1.1.0-cdh5.12.2 by Apache Hive
```